# how to get checkedlistbox items selected when clicking a row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview

**my DataGridView**

```
id       FN      LastN  City    Deg   Skillset        Gender

10       ma      Alex   Trichy  BE    .net,html,sql   Male      
11       giri    mani   Madu    BE    .net, java      Male
```

When I click id 10 I want my  checkedlistbox items(.net,html,sql) being checked.
c# plz..

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using javascript put a click event on every row of datagrid view

```
        dataGridView1.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowDataBound);

    void dataGridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            var r = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["RequesterCode"]);
            if (e.Row.DataItem is AC.CCBS.ServiceFactory.AndcWorkFlow.RequestView)
            {
                var s = e.Row.DataItem as AC.CCBS.ServiceFactory.AndcWorkFlow.RequestView;
                var r1 = s.RequestCode;
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick","DoSome(this);");
            }
        }
    }

<script DoSome>
DoSome=function(sender){
 //do something here
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur idea bro..but i dono javascript.got ans using..     string strSkills= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
   char[] splitchar = { ',' };
   string[] arrSkills = strSkills.Split(splitchar);
          if (arrSkills != null && arrSkills.Length > 0)
            {for (int i = 0; i < chklstSkillset.Items.Count; i++)
                {for (int j = 0; j < arrSkills.Length; j++)
                  {if(chklstSkillset.Items[i].ToString().ToLower() == arrSkills[j].ToLower())
                        { chklstSkillset.SetItemChecked(i,true);}